# Возвращаемое значение метода в Java

Tags: java, методы

Добрый день. Есть код :

```
public class SimpleThis {
int i = 0;
SimpleThis increment()
 {
   i++;
   return this;
 }
   void print()
   {
    System.out.println("i = " + i);
   }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleThis x = new SimpleThis();
    x.increment().increment().print();
    }
 }
```

Собственно возникли вопросы. Если тип возвращаемого значения - это имя класса, в моем случае это получается тип SimpleThis у метода increment, то что этот тип возвращает. Если я заменю

```
SimpleThis increment()
```

на

```
int increment()
```

то произойдет ошибка . Почему ? А второй вопрос состоял в том, что я не понимаю как работает эта строчка

```
x.increment().increment().print();
```

Answer (score 2):

Про второй. Работает оно так:берется объект х, к нему применяется метод increment(), возвращающий ссылку на объект х с инкременированным значением поля, к которой опять применяется метод increment() и опять возвращается ссылка на объект с уже дважды инкременированным значением поля, а затем к этой ссылке применяется метод print().

Про первый: возвращается не имя класса, возвращается ссылка на объект, с которым работал метод. Ошибка при замене типа произойдёт в двух местах: в самом объявлении метода, так как придётся возвращать значение int, а не ссылку на объект, и в строке с двумя вызовами инкремента, так как вернётся значение типа int, а к нему нельзя применить метод increment().

Comment: А почему мы должны вызывать ссылку на объект , а не int ? Ведь мы просто увеличивает переменную i на единицу. И почему если вернется значение int, к нему нельзя применять метод increment()?

Comment: Если смотреть именно по данному коду - если возвращать int, то надо менять код в методе main() Как вариант, ничего не возвращать в методе increment() и добавить метод getI(), который вернёт значение i в объекте твоего класса. В мэйне дважды вызываешь инкремент, а затем вызываешь getI(), то, что он вернёт в дополнительную переменную, а её уже выводишь. 
А нельзя к int применить метод increment(), потому что это примитивный тип данных, для него не определено такого метода, да и вообще методов.

Comment: что то не очень понятно. можете дать какой то источник почитать. а то я даже не знаю где искать ответ на такой вопрос(вопросы). искал в гугле "возвращаемое значение метода", но чего то подобного с разъяснением не нашел

Comment: Я кажется понял . ведь мы написали строчку "return this". А это значит, что мы вернули ссылку а не примитивное значение. Если написать возвращаемое значение метода increment как int, а затем поменять строку "return this" на "return this.i", то все будет работать. Я единственное не могу понять, как происходит работа в строке "x.increment().increment().print();"? Почему тогда в методе print тип возвращаемого значения void , а не SimpleThis, как в методе "increment" ?

Comment: Насчёт источника - сам учился по книге Хорстманна. 
Если возвращается ссылка на объект, то можно к этой ссылке применить методы, определенные в классе этого объекта. Я это называю "паровоз методов". Строку с двойным вызовом increment() можно развернуть так:
x = x.increment();
x = x.increment();
x.print();
А в методе print() нам не надо ничего возвращать, потому что по логике вещей он не модифицирует объект, он его просто выводит. А вот если бы модифицировал, да нам нужна была возможность строить "паровозы методов" - тогда был бы не void.

Comment: Кей Хорстман "Основі Программирования Java", абсолютно советую!!!

Answer (score 1):

функция должна возращать то значение, которое прописано в ее сигнатуре. Ничего удивительного в том, что функция возращает экземпляр класса(указатель на экземпляр), в котором она определена нет. Собственно это известный механизм , позволяющий выполнять функции друг за другом, мы получаем удобочитаемую и элегантную конструкцию вызовов.

Comment: минутка занудства - в сигнатуре не прописано возвращаемое значение. Сигнатура определяется именем метода и списком его параметров - их типами, числом и последовательностью.